# Most performant way to store and find overlap in (coordinate, id, time interval) triples

Tags: c#, data-structures, performance, collections, unity3d

Let me explain what I'm doing.
I have a grid based on integer coordinates like (5,5), (5,6) etc., and I have an algorithm `FindCells` that generates a list of (coordinate, interval) tuples. These represent information of what coordinate is occupied with a starting time and an ending time (the interval). `FindCells` runs multiple times for various timestamps per second and checks against a global storage of `Reservations`. Reservations have a format of (coordinate, reservation id, interval). If `FindCells` finds a cell that is already reserved at the input timestamp, it fails and discards everything found so far. If it doesn't find any conflicts, it retuns the list of (coordinate, interval) tuples.

After the (coordinate, interval) list is generated, it is merged into the `Reservations` storage to reserve the newly found coordinates at the specific times.

This means that, by design, the results of `FindCells` depend on eachother, which prevents parallelization. My problem is that `FindCells` is very computationally heavy.

One idea I had, was allowing `FindCells` to run in parallel, and then checking for collisions when joining the result into `Reservations`. But since the storage contains a lot of data I'm not sure if bruteforcing it would be more efficiant than just discarding the multithreaded idea, as it need to iterate over all cells and all reservations for each cell until I find a match.

I've also looked into Range Trees or Interval Trees, but it doesn't seem like they could fit my problem.

I've also thought about merging the `FindCells` result directly into the `Reservation` storage inline, but this would in the worst case create a lot off useless adding and removing in case the last found cell has a conflict.

I'm working with C# and the data structures I use for storage for now are `Dictionary<cell, Dictionary<id, interval>>` for the storage and `Dictionary<cell, interval>` for the output of `FindCells`. According to the profiler most performance is lost on the check of whether a cell is available or not inside `FindCells`. `FindCells` returns around 50000 cells per successful call.

The trivial solution would be to reduce cell size (granularity of the grid), but that would have other negative effects in what I'm doing.

`FindCells` is basically rastering a rectangle on the grid for various timesteps. Input are a starting time, a starting position, a polygon, a movement speed and a timestep. It then rasters the polygon (finds the occupied cells), and marks them as occupied for the current time step. Then it moves the polygon by a small amount (timestep is 100ms), captures all cells again, updates the intervals for already captured cells in the previous timestep(s) and adds newly found cells. This is repeated until the polygon reaches a specific destination.

Comment: Your description of what `FindCells` is supposed to do looks very unclear to me. What are the precise input parameters of `FindCells`? Is there some kind of geometric operation involved on the grid? Please clarify.

Comment: @DocBrown I've added a description.

Comment: maybe switch `Dictionary<cell, Dictionary<id, interval>>` to `Dictionary<cell, Dictionary<interval,id>>` but given the volumes and use you describe I would turn the whole problem on its head and use 4d matrix transformations

Comment: *3d i guess since your shape only moves in 2d space

Comment: just seen the unity 3d tag. I guess your trying to pixelise body collisions? there are probably much better ways of achieveing the effect you are trying to get. Describe what you are aiming for and repost to #gamedev

Comment: @Ewan I need to use this way of collision detection because it is part of a bigger algorithm. It also allows collision detection in space time rather than space only. Also, what do you mean by matrix transformations?

Comment: I mean I would use traditional vector methods to work out the collision point, time and swept out area and work back from that to the pixels. or not at all. If you just want the future colision you can do it fine with normal collision detection